# Flutter Testing: InputChip click on delete

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart

I use [InputChips](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputChip-class.html) in my app.

```dart
InputChip(
  key: Key(label.id),
  label: Text(label.name),
  onDeleted: () => deleteChip(),
),
```

I want now to create unit tests to test the delete function. Unfortunatly I found no way to press the delete icon of the chip in the unit test. With `await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('1')));` it's possible to find the chip. How can I now define that I want to click the delete icon on the chip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your finder is finding and tapping the `InputChip` itself, not the "X" on the Chip.**

Your finder should look something like:

```js
find.descendant(
      of: find.byKey(Key(label.id)),
      matching: find.byIcon(Icons.cancel),
    );
```

This says "find the descendent of the `InputChip` who is the `cancel` `Icon`. Then you can tap that if you'd like :)

When you're missing a tap-target, or aren't sure what is happening in the test, have a look at the console after running `debugDumpApp();`